# Loop randomly through multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have 2 arrays with both database rows in them, but i want to loop through both of them randomly

let's say these are my arrays :

```
var fruit = [ "apple", "banana", "strawberry", "coconut"];
var cars = [ "mercedes", "bmw", "audi", "ferrari"];
```

then my output should be :

```
apple banana mercedes strawberry bmw audi coconut ferrari
```

Comment: The JSON part of the above is completely irrelevant to your question, suggest removing it. You have arrays, as you said. That's all we need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a new fruit/car array:

```
var arr=fruit.concat(cars);
var result=[];
```

Then loop and take a random el out of the array and add it to our result:

```
for(i=arr.length;i>0;i--){
  result.push(arr.splice(Math.round(Math.random()*(arr.length-1)),1));
}
```

Then create a string and display it:

```
result=result.join(" ");
console.log(result);
```

http://jsbin.com/qasomoluke/edit?console